# xmlstarlet returns 1 with empty value

Tags: exit-code, xmlstarlet

I'm tring use `xmlstarlet` for parsing this file.xml:

```
<resultset>
<row>
 <field name="b">2</field>
 <field name="c"></field>
</row>
</resultset>
```

With first field evrithing is ok

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "resultset/row[1]/field[1]" file.xml
2
$ echo $?
0
```

But with second field `xmlstarlet` returns 1

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "resultset/row[1]/field[1]" file.xml
$ echo $?
1
```

In my case empty fields are normal. I want to parse its without xmlstarlet error.

UPDATE:
the same behavior with `field[@name="b"]`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'resultset/row/field[@name="b"]' file.xml
2
$ echo $?
0
```

and

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'resultset/row/field[@name="c"]' file.xml
$ echo $?
1
```

i want to distinguish the second case from the real error

UPDATE 2: The MAIN PROBLEM is:
If i try select  `[@name="c"]` and `[@name="not_exits"]` `xmlstarlet` returns the SAME exit code 1.
But file.xml has field name 'c', and does not have field with name 'not_exist'.

I want `xmlstarlet` prints empti string and return exit code 0 when file.xml contains empty field with the given name,
and returns non-null exit code when file.xml does not contain field with the given name at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you xpath expressions to

```
resultset/row/field[@name="b"]
```

and

```
resultset/row/field[@name="c"]
```

and see if it works.

Edit:
I'm not sure what exactly you are `echo`ing in your question, but if we assume your xml is in a file called `file.xml`, these expressions work with no errors:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "resultset/row/field[@name='b']" -v . --nl file.xml
```

and

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m "resultset/row/field[@name='c']" -v . --nl file.xml
```

Comment: look at UPDATE2 in my question

Comment: @SergeyZorin I'm not sure what the problem is on your side. Test it like this: Insert a random text value in "c"; something like: `<field name="c">xyz</field>`. Then run both expressions. The first should output `2`; the second should output `xyz`. If you don't get these outputs, then there's something wrong with your system/installation/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think `-n` or `--nl` does the trick to exit with 0 when there is empty match.
Together with `-m ... -v .` seems to do what OP wants.

```
# Empty match
$ echo "<field name=\"c\"></field>" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "field[@name='c']" -v . --nl

$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 0

# No match
$ echo "<field name=\"c\"></field>" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "field[@name='non_existent']" -v . --nl
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 1

# Non-empty match
$ echo "<field name=\"c\">xyz</field>" | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "field[@name='c']" -v . --nl
xyz
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
0 0
```

### Notes

This outputs non-empty string. For me it is not a problem, as I filter results later anyway.